# How to set imageview resource based on value of integer variable. Int= X //R.drawable.imageX

Tags: android, imageview, android-resources, imagesource

I would like to know,how to dynamicly set source of imageview. I have 150 images (d1,d2,d3.......,d150) and I have integer variable "DungeonLevel", that through some time changes from 1 to 150. And I dont know how to write it. When I tried to find it, it wasnt the same or I didnt get it. So sorry if you think its duplicate.

Comment: If `Int X ` contains a valid drawable id . You can set it with `setImageResource(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int X;
String imageName = "image" + X;
String uriOfImage = "@drawable/" + imageName;
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uriOfImage, null, getPackageName());
Drawable resourceDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(resourceDrawable);
```

Here `X` stands for your `DungeonLevel` which is between **1** to **150**.

Comment: Thank you :) And sorry for wasting your time.